# Express Session not persisting after CORS calls

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express, cors, express-session

*TL;DR:*

> Can't succeed persisting session across multiple APIs call performed
>   between a Backbone App and Node.js Server with Express,
>   Express-Session and Express-Cors. Looks like session is reinitialized/lost
>   after every call.

*Long version:*

I'm having a client Backbone/React/Flux application running on `localhost:3000` performing the following call on a Node.js server running on `localhost:4242`:

**Http calls**

> POST http://localhost:4242/api/session

```
 RESPONSE HEADERS
 Content-Type application/json; charset=utf-8
 Set-Cookie connect.sid=s%3AFeNYY5GQGvkyRvOym7DhysprePaQr7xP.BrxOPP56k9pDpxQPvwjDFaxkEYoHU%2FAEtNUIXGltqjI; Domain=http://localhost:3000; Path=/
 Vary Origin
 X-Powered-By Express
 access-control-allow-credentials   true
 access-control-allow-orign http://localhost:3000
 [...]

 REQUEST HEADERS
 Accept application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
 Content-Type application/json; charset=utf-8
 Cookie connect.sid=s%3AjP4iADZvRnDHbJcCE8H81Zy6TIehj9BJ.eDOTw44GcHqq8i2dslBGd43tXMQ22ENl31fRizdC8iA
 Host localhost:4242
 Origin http://localhost:3000
 Referer http://localhost:3000/login
 [...]
```

> GET http://localhost:4242/api/users

```
 RESPONSE HEADERS
 Content-Type application/json; charset=utf-8
 Set-Cookie connect.sid=s%3ARxf91_vLMBqzB6xN-0QFIIk_-SyBP9_8.F1Mr%2BVSkYNJ6MqnzO%2BsxxfwXRinIX6th80SoukG1QBM;Domain=http://localhost:3000; Path=/
 Vary Origin
 X-Powered-By Express
 access-control-allow-credentials   true
 access-control-allow-orign http://localhost:3000
 [...]

 REQUEST HEADERS
 Accept application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
 Content-Type application/json; charset=utf-8
 Cookie connect.sid=s%3AjP4iADZvRnDHbJcCE8H81Zy6TIehj9BJ.eDOTw44GcHqq8i2dslBGd43tXMQ22ENl31fRizdC8iA
 Host localhost:4242
 Origin http://localhost:3000
 Referer http://localhost:3000/login
 [...]
```

Basically the first call `POST /api/session` is logging-in the user and attempting to store an API token in the session. 
Second call `GET /api/users` is triggered right after the first one succeed, and retrieving user information.

**Backbone method**

Here's my Backbone method on the Session model for logging-in :

```
  login: (options) ->
    @set {user: options.user, password: options.password}
    @save ['user', 'password'],
      success: (data) =>
        @set({authenticated: true, accessToken: data.accessToken, password: null})
        options.success(data) # trigger the second call here
      error: (error) =>
        options.error(error)
```

And the call to /api/users in my UserStore

```
users: (options) ->
  @users.fetch
    success: (users) =>
      @users = users
      options.success(users)
```

Using those different options (I've overridden Backbone.sync in Backbone.Collection/Backbone.Model):

```
class UsersCollection extends Backbone.Collection

  url: '/api/users'
  model: UserModel

  sync: (method, model, options) ->
    options ?= {}
    options.url ?= @url
    options.dataType ?= 'json'
    options.contentType ?= "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    options.crossDomain ?= true
    options.xhrFields ?= {"withCredentials": true}
    super(method, model, options)
```

(Simplified version: same thing for both Models and Collection, using BaseCollection and BaseModel, where I am overridding the sync() method).

So that `Console.log(options)` in `Backbone.sync(method, model, options)` is returning :

```
{"url":"http://localhost:4242/api/session","dataType":"json","contentType":"application/json; charset=utf-8","crossDomain":true,"validate":true,"parse":true,"xhrFields":{"withCredentials":true}}
```

**Node.js setup and methods**

Here's my Node.js router setting-up Express :

```
BodyParser = require 'body-parser'
Session = require 'express-session'
Cors = require 'cors'

class Router

  constructor: (express) ->
    @express = express
    @express.use BodyParser.json()
    @express.use Cors(@corsConfig())
    @express.use Session(@sessionConfig())
    # Express routes are set here
    # @express.post '/api/session', (request, response) => [...]
    # @express.get '/api/users', (request, response) => [...]

  corsConfig: ->
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
    credentials: true

  sessionConfig: ->
    secret: 'whatever'
    cookie:
      secure: false
      httpOnly: false
      domain: 'http://localhost:3000'
```

Here's my Node.js method handling `POST /api/session`

```
  login: (request, response) ->
    session = request.session
    console.log JSON.stringify(session)
    console.log request.sessionID
    console.log '---------------------------------------------'
    if session.accessToken
      console.log 'session with token!'
      response.json {accessToken: session.accessToken}
    else
      console.log 'performing credentialAuthentication'
      user = request.body.user
      password = request.body.password
      @whatever.authentication
        user: user
        password: password
        success: (accessToken) ->
          request.session.accessToken = accessToken
          console.log JSON.stringify(session)
          console.log request.sessionID
          console.log '---------------------------------------------!!!'
          response.json {accessToken: accessToken}
          # also tried with response.send()
```

And the one handling `GET /api/users`

```
  @express.get '/api/users', (request, response) =>
    console.log JSON.stringify(request.session)
    console.log request.sessionID
    console.log '---------------------------------------------'
    [...]
```

**Node.js Log**

Here's the log:

```
  express:router dispatching OPTIONS /api/session
  express:router dispatching POST /api/session
{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"secure":false,"httpOnly":false,"path":"/"}}
zse18d2zrNRdEXPjFHF0gm3NkONb-_5V
---------------------------------------------
performing credentialAuthentication
{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"secure":false,"httpOnly":false,"path":"/"},
"accessToken":"ebab5010f9ece5ea984e4b73f9a46ef3"}
zse18d2zrNRdEXPjFHF0gm3NkONb-_5V
---------------------------------------------!!!
  express:router dispatching GET /api/users
{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"secure":false,"httpOnly":false,"path":"/"}}
g8YXQEpt_rnWSGdh1nCKMndiI8Lt2UDq
---------------------------------------------
```

As you can see the CORS request is performing normally, I am properly getting my token and then attempting to store it within the session.

**However in the second call the session isn't persisted and I can't access the variable (accessToken) that I am actually setting in my first call.**

Looking at the log and at the HTTP Headers of the two call, it looks like the session is reinitialized each time, as the session ID is changing and each request - and there is a Set-Request header sent every time (which shouldn't be the case, as far as I understand).

I suspect this behavior is caused by some incoherent or missing configuration at the CORS level, or due to the `path` set for Sessions (`Express.use(path, middleware)`, and `Cookie({path: '/'})`). However, despite many attempt with different configuration, setup and headers, I really can't make it work.

Anyone able to enlighten me on this behavior and what I am missing is very welcome :)
Thank you!

PS: My apologies to the non-CoffeeScript developers ;)

Comment: How are you calling `GET /api/users`, and with what options..?

Comment: BTW Are you adding the session middleware before both `POST` and `GET` handlers..? or are you using default in memory session store..? In case you happen to restart the server between these requests then new session will be created...I Know the probability is very less but in case if it helps :v

Comment: Well, I am setting the Session middleware in my Router class, and only then setting the express routes. Also tried to setup the Session middleware per express route, but of course it doesn't change anything :( 
Session should be stored in-memory, and of course I am not expecting the server to persist them if restarted; The two calls are performed in the same instance, right after each other, as you can see in the code.

Comment: For cookies to works over CORS the browser must support 3rd party cookies. Many browsers today blocking  it.

Comment: I am testing using the latest version of Firefox and Chrome; both support 3rd party cookies...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the answer (simple one): 
I had misconfigured my Session middleware; The `cookie.domain` options was causing the problem. 
Here's the proper configuration :

```
sessionConfig: ->
  secret: 'whatever'
  cookie:
    secure: false
    httpOnly: false
```

This option isn't required/existing (anymore?) with the express/session middleware; Not sure why I originally used it, probably something from an outdated reference (to express/cookie-parser or express/cors).

Comment: Hi, I am doing API call from my node js application to spring security application. I am getting ``Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found``. How can i solve this issue? I have tried to pass the ``X-XSRF-TOKEN`` in header but it seems i have to pass the session as well of existing request. Any idea?