# Value appears saved to Express Session but not accessible inside subsequent route

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, express, express-session

I have a problem saving data to the Express Session middleware. I am using a Vue.js frontend to communicate with the server which is running at `localhost:8080`. The server runs on `localhost:3002`.

I suspect that the interaction between the Vue app and the server may be the source of the problem as I have tried tests with a bare bones Express app that serves HTML as simple template literals and `req.session.save()` works fine.

Here is my code.

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  "transpileDependencies": [
    "vuetify"
  ],
  devServer: {
    "https": true
  }
}
```

index.js(Express server)

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'https://localhost:8080', // Have tried with and without these options 
  credentials: true,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// Set up app to use session 
let sess = {
  secret: 'What secret?', 
  resave: false, // Tried true
  saveUninitialized: false, // Tried true
  cookie: {secure: process.env.NODE_ENV=="prod",httpOnly: false}, // Tried true  
  store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: process.env.DB_URL, 
    ttl: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60  }) // = 14 days. Default 
}

app.use(session(sess));
```

Login route where data is being set to the session.

```
  app.post('/api/login', async (req, res) => {
     ...
      request(options, function (error, response) { 
        if (error) throw new Error(error)
        let fm_res = JSON.parse(response.body)
        req.session.FM_TOKEN = fm_res.response.token
        req.session.save()
        console.log('TOKEN STORED IN SESSION :: ', req.session) // token present in session here
        res.json({message: 'Token saved in session...', status: 200})
      });

});
```

Separate route where token is not accessible.

```
// CHECK AUTH
app.post('/api/token_auth', async (req, res) => {
  let authToken = req.session.FM_TOKEN
  console.log('TOKEN FROM SESSION : ', authToken) // undefined
  ....

});
```

I have researched and tried various solutions suggested here on SO but nothing I have found from any answers has worked. Can anyone point me in the right direction to solve this one as I am out of ideas. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I have tested the above endpoints with with Postman and they work, i.e. the `/api/token_auth` has access to the token saved on the session. So, it appears the problem might be connected to the fact that my frontend is not using `https` but `http` to make these calls.

I have tried using `httpOnly: false` setting in the `session.cookie` as suggested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33958907/express-session-not-persisting-after-cors-calls), but it still doesn't work. I am out of ideas.

Does anyone know how `https` requirement can be circumvented for development purposes?

Comment: By chance, app.post('/api/token_auth') is inserted before app.use(session(sess))?

Comment: @cassiolacerda No. All routes are declared after the app.use(session(sess)). Thanks for the reply!